# VSC not highlighting Vue 3 imports (Composition API)

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

As you can see below, the import is not highlited even though the component `SearchBar` is been used.

[image]

I've tried fixing this problem by installing the **Vetur** and **Vue 3 Support - All In One** extensions, but they don't fix it.

I would appreciate if someone could help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Vue Volar extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MisterJ.vue-volar-extention-pack) extension instead of **Vetur**

This is the official Vue.js language feature extension for VS Code

Comment: If you are using Typescript in you project then add `lang="ts"` on `<script>` tag. I'm not sure It will work but I also faced same problem and it fixed by just adding the lang.

Comment: Vue Volar Extension Pack solved the problem. Note for other people: I had to add `"jsx": "preserve"` in `compilerOptions` in `jsconfig.json` file to make the `<template>` tag work properly